# adding textbox in dataTable

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I want to add `textBox` in my `dataTable`.My `dataTable` is dynamically created and bind to `gridView`.When I try to add new row on button click gives me this error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

Parameter name: index

```
TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[0].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox1");
```

Here is my code:

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" 
        ShowHeader="true" 
        OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" 
                        CssClass="button2" 
                        OnClick="btnTest_Click"
                        Text="-" 
                        Width="100px" 
                        Font-Bold="True" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TextBox1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void AddNewRecordRowToGridf()
{
    //creating DataTable
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;

    dt.TableName = "Markici";
    //creating columns for DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirmaID", typeof(System.Int32)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Godina", typeof(System.Int32)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("KasaID", typeof(System.Int32)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MarkicaID", typeof(System.Int64)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Datum", typeof(System.DateTime)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Masa", typeof(System.Int32)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VrabotenID", typeof(System.Int32)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Artikal", typeof(System.String)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Cena1", typeof(System.String)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Kolicina", typeof(System.Decimal)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Smena", typeof(System.Int32)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VkIznos", typeof(System.Decimal)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VkDanok", typeof(System.Decimal)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SysDatum", typeof(System.DateTime)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Vid", typeof(System.String)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EdMera", typeof(System.String)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ArtikalID", typeof(System.String)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TarifaID", typeof(System.Int32)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Zabeleshka", typeof(System.String)));
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    ViewState["Markici2"] = dt;

    if (ViewState["Markici2"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici2"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[0].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox1");
                //Creating new row and assigning values

                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();

                drCurrentRow["FirmaID"] = Request.Cookies["firma"].Value;
                drCurrentRow["Godina"] = Request.Cookies["godina"].Value;
                drCurrentRow["KasaID"] = Request.Cookies["kasa"].Value;
                drCurrentRow["MarkicaID"] = Request.Cookies["kasa"].Value;
                drCurrentRow["Datum"] = DateTime.Now;
                drCurrentRow["Masa"] = Session["masa39"];
                drCurrentRow["VrabotenID"] = Session["New"];
                drCurrentRow["Artikal"] = Label12.Text;
                drCurrentRow["Cena1"] = Label13.Text;
                if (Session["MinusVrganj"] != null)
                {
                    drCurrentRow["Kolicina"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["MinusVrganj"]) + Counter; //Label5.Text; //count;
                }

                drCurrentRow["Kolicina"] = Label11.Text; //count;
                drCurrentRow["Smena"] = Session["smena1"];
                drCurrentRow["VkIznos"] = Label17.Text;//Counter1 * Convert.ToDecimal(Label13.Text); //Label17.Text;
                drCurrentRow["VkDanok"] = Label18.Text;
                drCurrentRow["SySDatum"] = DateTime.Now;
                drCurrentRow["Vid"] = Label24.Text;
                drCurrentRow["Edmera"] = Label16.Text;
                drCurrentRow["ArtikalID"] = Label34.Text;
                drCurrentRow["TarifaID"] = Label14.Text;
                drCurrentRow["Zabeleshka"] = TextBox1.Text;
            }
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
            //storing DataTable to ViewState
            ViewState["Markici"] = dtCurrentTable;

            //binding Gridview with New Row
            GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dont use cells when finding a control. framework with do that. `GridView2.Rows[0].FindControl("TextBox1");` and dont ask same question twice.

Comment: Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'TextBox1' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index     TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)GridView40.Rows[0].FindControl("TextBox1");